# Very large size photo : 2GB

Tags: photo-editing

I have an archive of photos which was taken by my IPhone 6. The size of each suddenly changed to 2 GB ! This made the total size of these photos folder to 700 GB while my hard disk size is only 100 GB. The initial size of folder was was about 1 GB only since every photo size in fact was about 3-4 MB. What should I do to repair them?

Comment: Can you define the type of archive that contains the photos, do you mean in a zip or rar file ? Also are these files or archives you try to repair, saved in your computer's hard disk or in iPhone's memory ?

Comment: they are just in a folder. neither zip not rar. just copied them from my iPhone to my laptop compute (windows 7) and after some days came to copy them to somewhere else which found this has happened to some of them.

Comment: It would be better to mention in your question by editing it, which was the initial size of each folder before its upwards growth

Comment: Just did so. Thanks. and I am doing as u said for "CHECK DISK".

Comment: Ok, let us know if my suggestion solved your issue. Better by continue commenting below the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably a damage in your Hard Disk's File System.

Please try to perform a chkdsk ([Check Disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK)) on the Hard Disk that contains the files:

1. Windows Key + R
2. Type "cmd" without quotes, to open command console
3. Inside the command console type "chkdsk **C:** /f" (without the quotes) and press enter
4. Windows will probably prompt you to restart your PC in order to perform the Check Disk procedure before Windows OS is loaded.
5. After it finished it will continue loading Windows. Check now if the problem solved.

**Note:** In case you have the files on another Hard Disk or Partition with different letter than "C:", replace it according to that Hard Disk or Partition drive letter.

Comment: unfortunately it did not solved the problem the problem :(